# Remove Backup and Factory reset option from Settings app

Tags: adb, settings, factory-reset, lineageos, disable-app

I want to remove some features from my settings app (device is rooted)

I used *adb shell pm disable 'com.android.settings/.Settings\$SecuritySettingsActivity'* to disable security settings and it worked. However, I am unable to find the activity name to disable backup and factory reset option.

[Here is the AndroidManifest.xml of the settings.apk](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_Settings/blob/cm-14.1/AndroidManifest.xml) (I'm using LineageOS)

So far I have tried

> adb shell pm disable 'com.android.settings/.BackupSettingsActivity'

and

> adb shell pm disable 'com.android.settings/.Settings\$PrivacySettingsActivity'

Both of which did absolutely nothing. I am still able to open backup and reset option from settings.

When I try to launch the said activities

> adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.BackupSettingsActivity

It errors out at saying BAD COMPONENT

while these two commands open the back and reset activity that I want to disable

> adb shell am start -a android.settings.BACKUP_AND_RESET_SETTINGS
>
> adb shell am start -S 'com.android.settings/.Settings\$PrivacySettingsActivity'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the activity was SubSettings (how intuitive!)

> adb shell pm disable 'com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings'

You can find the name of any activity that's onscreen. Use

> adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep 'mCurrentFocus'

Comment: 'com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings' seems to be various sections within settings, not just the Backup and Restore section. After disabling that, i am no longer able to change the PIN, for example.